# WEB CHAT: How to change the border color of cards in Web Chat?

Tags: botframework

I am using an MS Bot Framework Web Chat and change to accent from the default hard blue to a more soft blue like this:

```
const styleOptions = {
  accent: '#73ADC6',
  ...
```

This nicely changes the color of the user avatar but somehow the boarders of cards are still in the old hard blue. How can that be? How can I change the card border color?

I don't see any way when looking at the options here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js

Thanks a lot!

[border color of web chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2azU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons displayed in your attached image are a suggestedAction which is different from a card (you can reference these properties [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/packages/component/src/Styles/defaultStyleOptions.js#L97). A card is sent within the web chat transcript while the suggestedAction is attached to the sendBox. This allows the user to scroll while the buttons remain static while also allowing the buttons to disappear after a selection has been made.

At this time, there is no option available via Web Chat to alter the suggestedAction border color or other properties.

Therefore, you will need to directly change the CSS for the short term. Please be aware that this would affect all `button`s that will render. Place the following code in your `index.html` file. The "!important" identifier is necessary in order to override any web chat default styling for that element/class.

Hope of help!

```html
button {
  background-color: #73ADC6 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you also cannot get the `suggestedActionBorderColor` to register, please let me know. The feedback is important.

Comment: FYI, I had a couple devs near to me test their web chat using `suggestedActionBorderColor` and it worked fine for them, so this particular issue appears to be specific to me.

Comment: Another update: I spoke with a dev in the Web Chat team. The `suggestedActionBorderColor` and related properties aren't available in the current release. They are slated for an upcoming release. In the mean time, you will need to alter the CSS directly via the `button` element, as shown in the solution. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I never used this but in the documentation link you have sent, these two options appeare to do what you want.
bubbleFromUserBorderColor or bubbleBorderColor.
I think it is what you want.